# How could I set up a keyboard shortcut on my Mac that will open the camera on my iPhone, then transfer the captured photo to my Mac clipboard?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, finder, photos, copy-paste

I can right click in Finder and choose "Import from iPhone" => "Take Photo". This will open the camera on my iPhone. Then I can take a photo on my phone, and it will be saved to a folder on my Mac.

[image: Right click in Finder -> Import from iPhone]

One big advantage is that the photo is already in the JPEG format, so it can be easily imported into programs or websites. Taking a photo directly on the phone and then transferring it via Airdrop will give me an HEIC file, and I usually need to convert these to JPEG using Preview before they can be used.

However, I would like to take this one step further. I would like to set up a keyboard shortcut on my Mac which will open the camera on my iPhone. Once I take a picture on the phone, the picture will be copied to my clipboard on my Mac, so I can easily paste it into Slack, Evernote, email, etc.

Is there any way to automate the Finder -> Import from iPhone -> Take Photo workflow using Automator, AppleScript, or a command-line tool?

Automator has a "Take Picture" option, but it looks like it only works with digital cameras and hasn't been updated to support iPhones.

[image: Automator Photo Options]

I found a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078885/calling-finders-import-from-iphone-take-photo-from-shell) but I wasn't satisfied with the answer. "Cliclick" looks like a nice tool but I'd like to solve this in a cleaner way.

Comment: So edit the code to do what you want.

Comment: If you want to work around HEIC, you could either change the default format to JPG on the iPhone or set up a folder action to automatically convert the airdropped HEIC to JPG on the Mac. Or just extend the SO script to copy the resulting image to the clipboard.